# fancyBox options have no effect whatsoever

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

can anyone tell me what is wrong with the following code? I have been able to get fancyBox working right away, but no matter what i do, options have no effect, not even the height and width. It just stays the same default look..I have tried setting just a single option, none have any effect on the look.

```
$(".covers").fancybox({
'autoSize': false,
'height': 300,
'width': 400,
'closeClick': true,
'openEffect': 'elastic',
'closeEffect': 'elastic'
});
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you wrapped your fancybox code inside the `.ready()` method?

if you are opening images, `autoSize`, `width` and `height` won't work for them since their size is automatically calculated. Those options are for `iframe`, `inline` or `ajax` content (set `fitToView` to `false` may also be needed)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".covers").fancybox({
        autoSize: false, // doesn't work with images
        height: 300, // doesn't work with images
        width: 400, // doesn't work with images
        fitToView: false, // if you require exact size (400x300)
        closeClick: true,
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic'
    });
});
```

Apart from that your code works fine, see **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxxdG/)** (see elastic opening/closing effects and closing when clicking inside the content)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so how do I set a size for images that will open in the fancybox? they are very large images and setting fitToView as false expands them way beyond page constraints. Leaving it as is sets the image to cover almost the entire page, not really unattractive, but I wanted them to appear just a little smaller, but keeping the same aspect ratio of a DVD cover. I don't want to shrink them, since I want people to be able to left click and download them if they want to.

Comment: that didn't work, but thanks, because what did work was similar...setting maxHeight at 75% along with fitToView as false..Hooray

Comment: something weird is happening on this page: http://heavyjams.com/index.php?showID=755  when you open the image, the bottom of the webpage gets chopped off, until you close the image. very strange reaction..                                                                                         $(".covers").fancybox({
  'closeClick': true,
  'openEffect': 'elastic',
  'closeEffect': 'elastic',
  'maxHeight': "75%",
  'openSpeed': 'slow',
  'closeSpeed': 'slow'
 });                                                               yes it is inside document(ready)

Comment: that is because the normal `body` and `html` padding/margins when fancybox set overflow to hidden .... you may need to reset your page's default settings using normalize http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ or Eric Meyer's reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: neither of those worked here. is it a particular margin that i can adjust? you are saying that fancybox is changing the overflow when it opens the image? thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep, fancybox changes the overflow of your page but you can disable the lock feature and you won't see that weird effect on your page. Check http://jsfiddle.net/XaWZE/ to learn how to disable the overlay `locked` feature.